# PowerShell in C#; Creating an 'initialSessionState', 'connectionInfo', and putting them in the same Runspace

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-remoting

I am trying to create a runspace that contains both an initialSessionState (shown below) and a connectionInfo (also below).  I would like the PowerShell api to set the execution policy to unrestricted, then to run a powershell script on a remote computer.

```
InitialSessionState initialSessionState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
initialSessionState.ExecutionPolicy = ExecutionPolicy.Unrestricted;

WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo();
connectionInfo.ComputerName = "VMD_CLEAN_RDP";
connectionInfo.Credential = creds;
```

I'm creating the runspace like this:

```
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initialSessionState))
```

After this step, is it possible to add connectionInfo to the runspace somehow? or the other way around (by creating the runspace with connectionInfo then adding an initialSessionState)

If it is possible to add a remote computer location after creating the PowerShell object, that would be great also! but I haven't been able to find any examples of that yet.
An example:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create()
{
  ps.AddRemoteComputer(remoteCompuuterName);
  ps.AddCredentials(creds)
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if you need more explanation (or more of my code for guidance), do let me know as I'm new here and I'm not fully sure how much is necessary.

Thank you very much all,

I have tried to run my PowerShell scripts with the connectionInfo within the runspace, and while it connects to the remote computer that way, the scripts won't run.  If I try it the other way around, the scripts run, but they only run locally on my machine.